# How to fire an event on browser closing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Hello guys,

I have problem to detect the session end when the browser is closed, how can i get this, i want to fire a query to store the login time information in database, please help me.
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hidden button and then fire the button click event using

```
function doUnload()
{
 if (window.event.clientX < 0 && window.event.clientY < 0)
 {
   document.getElementByID('HiddenButton').click() }
}
<body onunload="doUnload()">
```

Never tried it but it might work :)

or you could use the global.aspx methods

```
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

do something;
        }

```
    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

do something;
        }

Sp

Comment: -1 Application_End is not directly related to the client activity and Session_End is not reliable because it's fired after an amount of time session has been inactive

Comment: I suppose it depends how accurate they require it to be. just thought id throw it out there. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unreliable to rely on that, An ajax query may not be completed on browser close.

**Solution:**

Sending a heartbeat request every `x` seconds in order to tell if the user left or not.

Comment: The very last thing we need on the Internet is websites abusing AJAX for "heartbeat" requests.

Comment: @meagar i agree, i don't know why the asker exactly want to sign up the user on browser close rather than the traditional way. i thought he was building a real time analytics service..